# Problems with highlighting a single row in an array block

Tags: tables, color, arrays

As shown in the image below, I am trying to create a simplex table by highlighting the pivot row and pivot coloumn. However I come across an issue when I highlight the pivot row as the command fills the pivot row and all the rows below it. How can I resolve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
 \newcommand\Circle[1]{%
   \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h]
  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{array}{cc}
          \\
       & z \\ 
     0 & s_1 \\
     0 & s_2 \\
     0 & s_3 \\
     $-3$ & x_{1} \\
   \end{array}

   \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{cccccc|cc}
     x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & b & \theta \\ \hline
     0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 & \\ \hline
     \rowcolor{red!20}
     0 & \Circle{$2$} & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\ 
     0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
    \end{array}
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to put `\rowcolor{white}` after that row.

Comment: if i do then i have issues when highlighting the column because any column elements belonging to rows after the pivot row will be white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more natural to colour by columns, which gives some  control on the width of the coloured column. Here is a solution. I changed some parameters to improve the visual aspect of the highlighting (at leats to my taste…)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
 \newcommand\Circle[1]{%
   \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h]
 \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{array}{cc}
          \\
       & z \\
     0 & s_1 \\
     0 & s_2 \\
     0 & s_3 \\
     $-3$ & x_{1} \\
   \end{array}
%
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{c >{\columncolor{PaleVioletRed3!20}[0pt][0pt]}ccccc|cc}
     x_1 & \cellcolor{white}{x_2} & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & b & \theta \\ \hline
     0 & \cellcolor{white}{-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 & \\ \hline
     0 & \Circle{$2$} & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{array}
   \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a `row-and-column highlighting`, it doesn't seem possible to do both with `colortabl, so I propose to make row-highlighting with`pstricks`. Roughly I add empty nodes at the beginning and at the end of the highlighting zone, and I connect them with an`\ncbox` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h]
 \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{equation*}
\begin{postscript}
   \begin{array}{cc}
          \\
       & z \\
     0 & s_1 \\
     0 & s_2 \\
     0 & s_3 \\
     $-3$ & x_{1} \\
   \end{array}
%
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{c >{\columncolor{PaleVioletRed3!20}[-0.7pt][-0.7pt]}ccccc|cc}
     x_1 & \cellcolor{white}{x_2} & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & b & \theta \\ \hline
     0 & \cellcolor{white}{-2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 & \\ \hline
    \pnode{B}0 & \circlenode[linewidth=0.4pt, framesep=1pt]{P}{$2$} & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 2\pnode{E} \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3\\
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{array}%
\ncbox[nodesep=3pt, boxsize=2.1ex, boxdepth=0.6ex, linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=PaleVioletRed3, opacity=0.2]{B}{E}
   \end{bmatrix}%
\end{postscript}
  \end{equation*}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to highlight the pivot row as well, but thanks for the response!

Comment: @K_Jay: it wasn't mentioned initially.  I propose a simple solution based on `pstricks` (and I replace the \Circle command defined with Tikz with the equivalent command from pst-node). Please see my completed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it feels like a hack than an actual solution.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

 \usepackage{tikz}
  \newcommand\Circle[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}

 \begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{cc}
        \\
   & z \\ 
 0 & s_1 \\
 0 & s_2 \\
 0 & s_3 \\
 $-3$ & x_{1} \\
 \end{array}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{c>{\columncolor{yellow!20}}ccccc|cc}
x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & b & \theta \\ \hline
0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 6 & \\ \hline
\rowcolor{red!20}
0 & \Circle{$2$} & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\ 
\rowcolor{white}
0 & \cellcolor{yellow!20} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 \\
0 & \cellcolor{yellow!20} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3\\
1 & \cellcolor{yellow!20} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}
 \newcommand\Circle[1]{%
   \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{rccccccc|cl}[colortbl-like]
   &     & x_1 & x_2        & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & b & \theta\;\;\\
\cline{3-10}
   & z   & 0   & -2         & 0   & 0   & 0   & 3   & 6 &        \\
\cline{3-10}
0  & s_1 & \rowcolor{red!15}
           0   & \Circle{2} & 1   & 0   & 0   & -1  & 4 & 2      \\
0  & s_2 & 0   & 1          & 0   & 1   & 0   & -2  & 4 & 4      \\
0  & s_3 & 0   & 1          & 0   & 0   & 1   & 1   & 3 & 3      \\
-3 & x_1 & 1   & 0          & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 2 & 0      \\
\CodeAfter \SubMatrix[{1-3}{6-10}][left-xshift=1.3mm]
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]